# Refreshing a sub form on the close of a pop up form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to refresh the sub form "frmProjGovernanceDetail02" which is embedded in the main form "frmProjGovernanceDetailSwitchboard" on the close of a pop up form which is opened from the sub form.

It seems my syntax for the below code is not correct. If someone could give me a hand i would really appreciate it.

```
Forms("frmProjGovernanceDetailSwitchboard").Form("frmProjGovernanceDetail02").Refresh
```

Comment: Use:  Forms![frmProjGovernanceDetailSwitchboard]![MySubForm].Form.Refresh     .... NOTE! Change MySubForm to the name of the control on your main form that contains your subform - not the actual name of the saved form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Forms![frmProjGovernanceDetailSwitchboard]![frmProjGovernanceDetail02].Form.Requery
```